# My code in UIView init has no effect if I don't delay its execution

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, view, delay

I'm building a color picker in Swift. I have a view controller which houses a custom view that I built via code. This view is the "ColorWheelView" for which I have a custom init. This color wheel obviously houses the wheel of colors and a little circular view, a draggable pointer to pick colors.

As I said, I have this custom init:

```
init(radius: CGFloat, color: UIColor? = nil) {
    self.radius = radius
    self.color = color
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    
    self.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.clipsToBounds = false
    setupGraphic()

    if let color = color {
        applyColor(_ color: color)
    }
}
```

`setupGraphic()` is a method of my view with which I create and constraint my subviews.

`color` is an optional parameter that I pass to the view if I want to present my color picker with a pre-selected color. If color exists, I execute the `applyColor` function that does some little calculations to obtain the position of the pointer in the wheel.

I create and position the "ColorWheelView" in the `loadView()` of my view controller.

Despite calculations are ok (I saw with a breakpoint that the calculated position is correct), the pointer remains at (x: 0, y: 0). But **if I delay the execution** of `applyColor`, the pointer correctly changes its position. Even if I execute it on main thread (despite I'm already on main thread), the pointer correctly changes its position. Why should I add this delay, or send my code on main thread? What I'm missing?

**EDIT**:

Here's `applyColor` method:

```
func applyColor(_ color: UIColor) {
    var hue = CGFloat(0)
    var sat = CGFloat(0)
    var bri = CGFloat(0)
        
    color.getHue(&hue, saturation: &sat, brightness: &bri, alpha: nil)
    brightnessView.alpha = 1 - bri
        
    let radius = sat / 2
    let angle = (hue + cent) * (CGFloat.pi * -2)
    let pos = CGPoint(x: ((radius * cos(angle)) + cent) * (self.radius * 2),
                      y: ((radius * sin(angle)) + cent) * (self.radius * 2))
        
    brightnessSlider.setValue(Float(bri), animated: false)
    getColor(at: getNormalizedPosition(pos))
    pointerView.center = pos
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because when `init()` method get called your view is not fully constructed. If you apply it main thread (although you are already on main) it apply that after some delay...(in that delay view construct so your code gives you proper results).. Mainly you add constraint in `layoutSubviews()`. In this method you apply constraints or do frame related things

Comment: I'm still not fully convinced. Just before the applyColor call, all the subviews are created. In the apply color method I also set the value for a UISlider and change colors of some other subviews. And it works. Why only the pointer positioning needs for delay?

Comment: can you post your `applyColor()` method ?

Comment: `pointerView.center = pos` issue with this line ... center is not determined when this code executed ...

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know about this.